# SMTP Problem with vb6

Tags: vb6

I am developing SMTP Client to send email from my application.

I am able to send email but From field in the inbox of the destination email was empty.

It is showing (unknown sender).

Please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a

```
"From: NAME <EMAIL>" & vbCrLf
```

To your header string.

Also, be sure to check out [vbSendMail.dll](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=109). Not only is it a complete working dll you can just reuse - you also have the source to consult in case you *insist* (great learning experience?) on writing this by yourself.

Comment: got it working now.Previously i  inserted name in MAIL FROM Header.But now i am supposed to send attachments also.Please guide me.

Comment: ramu, sending attachments is going to be a lot harder. you will have to read up on MIME and all the relevant RFCs. There *has* to be a component that does this already!

Comment: Also, look into the MAPI stuff - you might find that the easiest way to do email in VB6 on windows. But then, VB6 is rather windows only ;)